# How to keep showing the value of label again in form when the answer is not correct

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
namespace Game
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        String[] word = { "Ordinary", "Darkness", "Marriage" };
        Random rnd = new Random();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = word[rnd.Next(0, word.Length)];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string guess;
            guess = textBox1.Text;

            while (guess != label1.Text)
            {
                if (guess != label1.Text)
                    MessageBox.Show("You got it right");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("You got it wrong");
            }      
        }
```

When i type a wrong word which will drop to else, the form after that will not show the word on label. Im quite new to c# send help.

Comment: `guess != label1.Text` = Doesn't this mean the guess was *wrong*, not that it was *right*?

Comment: oh then i will change to == so the guess will be equal to label1, my question is if i typed wrong answer to textbox, after that the form will dont show the label already which the one you need to guess

Comment: Why are you showing the random word in a label? If the secret word is visible, guessing becomes pointless. Better store it in a class variable (field).

Comment: Oh i want to turn the words i put there to jumbled words, the user just need to arrange it.

Answer (score 2):

First, this logic is incorrect:

```
if (guess != label1.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You got it right");
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("You got it wrong");
```

The comparison operator should be `==`.  Otherwise it would be a *very* easy game (guessing *literally any string* which doesn't match the target string).

Once you correct that, consider what you're doing here:

```
while (guess != label1.Text)
{
    if (guess == label1.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You got it right");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("You got it wrong");
}
```

So, if the guess is *incorrect*, what happens here?  The loop continues, over and over, infinitely.  So the program essentially "locks up" and becomes unresponsive because the logic is busy infinitely looping over a condition that never changes within that loop.

Taking a step back... Why do you even have this loop?  All you want to do in this button click handler is check the answer, so just check the answer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("You got it right");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("You got it wrong");
}
```

No need for a loop at all because there's no operation to *repeat*.  This logic will already be re-invoked any time the button is clicked.

Comment: https://imgur.com/lg6a44e after i type the wrong answer, the label will not show already and i cant get to type it again https://imgur.com/FiJo8Pg

Comment: @cookie: Are you sure this is all of the code?  I don't see anything that's modifying that table in any way.

Comment: Yea that's all, the form1 is just for the user to choose difficulty that will direct them to that form 2, which is where you need to type. It's lacking of code

Comment: @cookie: In that case I'm [unable to replicate the problem](https://dev.azure.com/DavidD0205/_git/Sandbox?path=/WinFormsApp1).  You'll need to provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the whole while loop doesn't make much sense to me as the check seems a bit odd. Don't you want to check if the guess is equal to the label and if not show "you've got it wrong on the screen" and you don't really need the while around the whole thing.

```
        if (guess == label1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You got it right"); 

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You got it wrong");
        }
```

Comment: yea, i did change already to == then i dont need to loop it already for the program to keep ask if my answer was wrong?